# Java: parse Array of Arrays from JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON Arrays of Array like this

```
{
    "width" : 500,
    "numbers" : [ 
        [46, 11, "1674"],
        [46, 11, "1673"],
        [46, 11, "1677"],
        [46, 11, "1678"],
        [46, 11, "1674"],
        [46, 11,  1673]
    ]
}
```

And i don't know how to parse it.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("numbers");
```

This code throws a type missmatch error.

Comment: What Json library do you use? It might not be able to cope with the mixed types inside the inner arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try GSON, the following should do the trick:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ReadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("json.txt"));

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    A a = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);

    System.out.println(a.width);
    System.out.println(a.numbers[0][0]);
    }
}


public class A {
    public int width;
    public int numbers[][];
}
```