# json simple parse array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, json, matrix, json-simple

I found a way to parse array of arrays in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345359/java-parse-array-of-arrays-from-json) with gson.. but I need it with json simple..

here's my json file:

```
{
"matrix" : [
    [6,"",3,8,"A"],
    ["","B",1,"A",9]
]
}
```

The arrays are made of strings, integers and null, is there a way to parse them into an ArrayList of ArrayList of objects so when I use it I can cast these single values into the right type?

Comment: Yes. Use ArrayList<Object>

Comment: you will not find more simpler

Comment: What is the problem using Gson?

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: What is 'ArrayList' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this it's very simple**

```
//This is your Some Class let say CustomObject

class CustomObject implements Serializable {

List<ArrayList<Object>> matrix;

public List<ArrayList<Object>> getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}

public void setMatrix(List<ArrayList<Object>> matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}
}
```

> If your string input is as shown in question then below code is works fine. (In Question you missed ',' at the end of first array in matrix)

```
    CustomObject customObject = new Gson().fromJson(input, CustomObject.class);

    System.out.println(customObject.matrix.size());

    System.out.println("DONE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `org.json` packages. They offer easy ways to parse JSON. See this question(maybe you searched and didn't find it?)

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answers suggest this:

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Or, Jackson:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

There is no built-in ways to do it.